# undefined method when using Sidekiq's delayed_extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, undefined, sidekiq

When using [Sidekiq's delayed extensions](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions), I get this error in my `bundle exec sidekiq` shell:

```
2013-03-06T04:13:57Z 52099 TID-ouqzj4xl8 WARN: undefined method `send_message' for #<Class:0x007f8a783d72f0>
```

**In my controller:**

```
MyClass.delay_until(10.seconds.from_now, :retry => true).send_message(deliver_sms, phone)
```

**In my model:**

```
require 'sidekiq'

class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Sidekiq::Extensions

  def self.send_message(deliver_sms, phone)
    message_id = deliver_sms.deliver(phone, 'This is a test message') 
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with Ruby < 1.9.3 according to this thread on Github: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/152#issuecomment-5281759

I had the same issue and upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3 fixed it. Any chance you are using 1.9.2?

Comment: Thanks. I think this was the problem. Do you know how to specify Ruby 1.9.3 when running sidekiq from the Procfile on Heroku?